# How to write an HTML Pattern attribute?

Tags: javascript, html

I want an HTML Pattern attribute in order to have only letters A-Z, a-z, 0-9, and spaces.

I have the following which work, but the only problem is that, it also accepts it if I just enter a space and click submit.

```
[A-Za-z 0-9]+
```

For that reason I decided I am going to require atleast 3 characters, one of them being a letter. That lead me to write this:

```
[A-Za-z 0-9](?=.*[A-Za-z]).{3,}
```

But on this one, if I enter Jui;18 it accepts it. an since this is going to based into sql, that will create problems. Why does it accept the semicolon and what is the right pattern I need?

Comment: "based into sql"? What kind of problems? Not SQL injection, I hope; you should be using parameterized queries. Client-side validation like the `pattern` attribute wouldn’t help anyway.

Comment: @Ryan It is SQL injection because I have a PHP file that creates a database in the name entered in the text field. What do you recommend for me to solve the problem, then?

Comment: Why are you creating databases dynamically? But you would at least validate it on the server side with the same pattern. Test that this part is safe without the `pattern` attribute on the client, then add it.

Comment: I wouldn't allow a space in a database name.

Comment: @AndyG I am removing the Space in php side, but adding with slace into a table

Comment: @Ryan How would I do a php verification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with your pattern:

```
[A-Za-z 0-9]+
```

Require at least 3 characters:

```
[A-Za-z 0-9]{3,}
```

Require a letter:

```
(?=.*[A-Za-z])[A-Za-z 0-9]{3,}
```